# I can't receive push notifications when my app is running and if it is closed i receive the notifications

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I'm working with push notifications with firebase. I can receive notifications
when my app is closed or in the background but I am not receiving notifications
when my app is running please help me so I can get notifications even when my app is running

```
  @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    shownotifeaction(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

public void shownotifeaction(String message) {
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Splash_Img.class), 0);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setContentTitle("Porwal")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

}

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Comment: attach your code.

Comment: I would advice you to include your code into your question. It will increase the chances that you can receive help and reduce the chances to have your question flagged and closed.

Comment: use data message and then manually show notification.

Comment: Please post code of what you have done

Comment: Thanks all for the response I relay appreciation

Comment: Here is my cord pls help thank you  all

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to try this form of json from your server :

```
{ 
"data": 
{ 
"title":"FCM Message", "Body":"This is an FCM Message" }, 
"to" : "devicetoken"
}
```

Explanation:

notification - messages that goes directly to Android's Notification tray only if your application is in background/killed or gets delivered to onMessageReceived() method if your app is in foreground.

Data payload - Doesn't matter whether your application is in forground or background or killed, these messages will always be delivered to onMessageReceived() method.

Comment: *I don't know how your code is* - then don't guess the answer. For all we know he already is sending data payload